# Freemarker - access static variables of an object

Tags: freemarker

I have a simple class:

```
public class MyClass {

     public final static long MAIN = 1;

     @Setter @Getter
     protected int id;
}
```

(`@Setter` `@Getter` are `lombok` annotations for Setter and Getter methods.)

In Freemarker template I would like to create a condition like:

```
<#if myClassInstance.id == myClassInstance.MAIN>
```

But the right hand side of the `if` expression is according to FreeMarker undefined. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template language is not aware of Java classes. But you can expose static members through the data-model (template context). See: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_55

Comment: Thanks - this I have already seen. What I don't understand is why the static objects of the class are not wrapped with the instance? I was not trying MyClass.MAIN, but myClassInstance.MAIN.

Comment: Maybe it just didn't occur to the author of `BeansWrapper` back then... But, I think that wouldn't be a real solution of the problem anyway, because sometimes you want to access static members when there's no instance around. Something like `"com.example.MyClass"?statics` would be more appropriate (although it calls for yet another class-loading based security setting -- `?new` already has one).

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question already have an accepted answer but I am still writing piece of code that can be help full for some one else.

**Use below piece of code in java**

```
BeansWrapper w = new BeansWrapper(); 
TemplateModel statics = w.getStaticModels(); 
map.put("statics", statics); // map is java.util.Map
template.process(map, out); // template is freemarker.template.Template
```

**Then access constant in ftl**

```
${statics["com.model.to.gen.Common"].FLAG_YES}
```

here **com.model.to.gen.Common** is a class and **FLAG_YES** is a static constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **expose fields** option. So you can use data models without accessors (getters/setters).

```java
BeansWrapperBuilder wrapperBuilder = new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
wrapperBuilder.setExposeFields(true);

Template     template     = freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("mytemplatefile.ftl");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

template.process(model, stringWriter, wrapperBuilder.build());

System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another similar but **effective** way.
First, we can create a util class like this:

```
/**
 * FreeMarker Utils.
 *
 * @author Eric Chan
 */
public abstract class FreeMarkerUtils {

    /**
     * init for static classes and fields.
     *
     * @param model model
     */
    public static void initStatics(final Model model) {
        // you can also create the Version like: new Version("2.3.27");
        BeansWrapper wrapper = new BeansWrapper(new Version(2, 3, 27));
        TemplateModel statics = wrapper.getStaticModels();
        model.addAttribute("statics", statics);
    }

}
```

And next, invoke it in your `Controller`:

```
FreeMarkerUtils.initStatics(model);
```

That's all, now you can access static variables in your `.ftl` like this:

```
${statics["com.springboot.constants.TestConstants"].NAME}
```